# How do I get IModel.BasicAcks to fire?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I'm playing with RabbitMQ's .NET API for the first time, and I came up with a use case that seems plausible to me: I want to create publisher that publishes messages and does something after they've been Ack-ed. the IModel.BasicAcks event seemed like a decent way to find out about this, so--

I wrote a publisher:

```
       private static void Post(string message) {

            model.ExchangeDeclare("MyExchange", ExchangeType.Fanout, true);
            model.QueueDeclare("MyQueue", true, false, false, null);
            model.QueueBind("MyQueue", "MyExchange", "", new Dictionary<string, object>());

            byte[] messageBodyBytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            IBasicProperties props = model.CreateBasicProperties();
            props.ContentType = "text/plain";
            props.DeliveryMode = 2;
            model.BasicPublish("MyExchange", "", props, messageBodyBytes);
    }
```

And a subscriber:

```
    private static void Receive() {
            var gotten = model.BasicGet("MyQueue", false);
            var text = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetString(gotten.Body);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            model.BasicAck(gotten.DeliveryTag, false);
    }
```

And this is the entry point for the Console App:

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {

        connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.HostName = "localhost";
        connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        model = connection.CreateModel();
        model.BasicAcks += new RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicAckEventHandler(model_BasicAcks);
        Post("Hello, World!");
        Receive();
        Console.ReadKey();

        connection.Dispose();
        model.Dispose();

    }
```

For some reason, my event handler is not being called. The "Hello, World!" message gets published, read, Acked, and printed to the console, but for some reason the event handler is never called.

Am I doing something wrong? Subscribing to IModel.ModelShutdown seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll refer the curious to the response that I got from the RabbitMQ team on this question.

[Here's what they had to say](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-May/012663.html)

Briefly put, the event fires, but it's not what I thought it might be-- it's for Publisher Confirms, [explained in this RabbitMQ blog post](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/)

Answer (score 0):

After a LOT of experimenting with the api, here is what worked for me. I needed to declare my event handlers before declaring my exchange and queues.

```
_rabbitMqChannel.BasicAcks += new BasicAckEventHandler(_rabbitMqChannel_BasicAcks);
_rabbitMqChannel.BasicNacks += new BasicNackEventHandler(_rabbitMqChannel_BasicNacks);

_rabbitMqChannel.ExchangeDeclare(ExchangeName, ExchangeTypeVal.ToString());
_rabbitMqChannel.QueueDeclare(QueueName, QueueDurable, QueueExclusive, QueueDelete, null);
_rabbitMqChannel.QueueBind(QueueName, ExchangeName, RoutingKey);
```

and here is how the event handlers methods will look like...

```
private void _rabbitMqChannel_BasicNacks(IModel model, BasicNackEventArgs args)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void _rabbitMqChannel_BasicAcks(IModel model, BasicAckEventArgs args)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Spent half day on this !! Hope this helps some one ;)

Comment: this gives me the error : 
The type or namespace name 'BasicAckEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: i am using rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.5-dotnet-4.5 
could it be they took it off in this recent version ?
could you provide your version number ?
i need this to work for me please.

Comment: i have made a new query on so, perharps you can assist to answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747226/the-type-or-namespace-name-basicackeventhandler-could-not-be-found-are-you-mi