# The type or namespace name 'BasicAckEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am trying to implement publisher confirms in c#, and trying the following code i found on SO.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18211367/3139595

```
_rabbitMqChannel.BasicAcks += new BasicAckEventHandler(_rabbitMqChannel_BasicAcks);
_rabbitMqChannel.BasicNacks += new BasicNackEventHandler(_rabbitMqChannel_BasicNacks);

_rabbitMqChannel.ExchangeDeclare(ExchangeName, ExchangeTypeVal.ToString());
_rabbitMqChannel.QueueDeclare(QueueName, QueueDurable, QueueExclusive, QueueDelete, null);
_rabbitMqChannel.QueueBind(QueueName, ExchangeName, RoutingKey);
and here is how the event handlers methods will look like...

private void _rabbitMqChannel_BasicNacks(IModel model, BasicNackEventArgs args)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void _rabbitMqChannel_BasicAcks(IModel model, BasicAckEventArgs args)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

this answer seems to have worked for him, but i am getting the following error .

```
The type or namespace name 'BasicAckEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am using the current version of rabbitmqdotnet dll :  rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.5-dotnet-4.5

could it bee they too off BasicAckEventHandler from the recent version ?
or i'm i missing anything there?

NB: i have the following using statements

```
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
```

Comment: It would seem that they removed those events in favor of `EventHandler<BasicAckEventArgs>`.  I found **[this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/sPSP3ulG6sg/PksDKvISWOwJ)**

Comment: @ChrisDunaway do you know how i can convert my script above to use this new EventHander<BasicAckEventArgs> 

do i need to change these lines?

_rabbitMqChannel.BasicAcks += new BasicAckEventHandler(_rabbitMqChannel_BasicAcks);
_rabbitMqChannel.BasicNacks += new BasicNackEventHandler(_rabbitMqChannel_BasicNacks);

Comment: I think you just need `_rabbitMqChannel.BasicAcks += _rabbitMqChannel_BasicAcks;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.5.0, RabbitMqdotNet guy replaced BasicAckEventHandler types with 
EventHandler , see how i finally wrote my publisher.
Thanks to @Chris Dunaway's comment that pointed me to this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/sPSP3ulG6sg/PksDKvISWOwJ)

```
    public bool publish(string message)
    {
        var appSettings = config.getAppSettings();

        string HostName = appSettings["RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME"];
        string UserName = appSettings["RABBITMQ_USERNAME"];
        string Password = appSettings["RABBITMQ_PASSWORD"];

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = HostName,
            UserName = UserName,
            Password = Password
        };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            bool successful = false;
            var responseReceivedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            string exchangeName = appSettings["RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE"];
            string routingKey = appSettings["RABBITMQ_ROUTING_KEY"];
            Dictionary<string, object> headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            channel.BasicAcks += (model, args) =>
            {
                successful = true;
                responseReceivedEvent.Set();
            };

            channel.BasicNacks += (model, args) =>
            {
                successful = false;
                responseReceivedEvent.Set();
            };

            channel.ConfirmSelect();
            channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, ExchangeType.Topic, true, false, null);
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            IBasicProperties props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            props.ContentType = constants.RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE;
            props.ContentEncoding = constants.RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_CONTENT_ENCODING;
            props.DeliveryMode = constants.RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT;
            props.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            props.AppId = constants.APP_ID;
            props.Type = constants.RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_TYPE;
            props.Headers = (IDictionary<string,object>)headers;
            props.Headers.Add("version", constants.VERSION);
            props.Timestamp = new AmqpTimestamp();

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: exchangeName,
                                 routingKey: routingKey,
                                 basicProperties: props,
                                 body: body);

            responseReceivedEvent.WaitOne();
            return successful;
        }

    }public bool publish(string message)
    {
        var appSettings = config.getAppSettings();

        string HostName = appSettings["RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME"];
        string UserName = appSettings["RABBITMQ_USERNAME"];
        string Password = appSettings["RABBITMQ_PASSWORD"];

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = HostName,
            UserName = UserName,
            Password = Password
        };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            bool successful = false;
            var responseReceivedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            string exchangeName = appSettings["RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE"];
            string routingKey = appSettings["RABBITMQ_ROUTING_KEY"];
            Dictionary<string, object> headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            channel.BasicAcks += (model, args) =>
            {
                successful = true;
                responseReceivedEvent.Set();
            };

            channel.BasicNacks += (model, args) =>
            {
                successful = false;
                responseReceivedEvent.Set();
            };

            channel.ConfirmSelect();
            channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, ExchangeType.Topic, true, false, null);
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            IBasicProperties props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            props.ContentType = constants.RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE;
            props.ContentEncoding = constants.RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_CONTENT_ENCODING;
            props.DeliveryMode = constants.RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT;
            props.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            props.AppId = constants.APP_ID;
            props.Type = constants.RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_TYPE;
            props.Headers = (IDictionary<string,object>)headers;
            props.Headers.Add("version", constants.VERSION);
            props.Timestamp = new AmqpTimestamp();

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: exchangeName,
                                 routingKey: routingKey,
                                 basicProperties: props,
                                 body: body);

            responseReceivedEvent.WaitOne();
            return successful;
        }

    }
```